# Ubuntu lost GNOME installation, cyclic dependencies when reinstalling GNOME

Tags: gnome, ubuntu-10.04, swf, gdm

Take a look [here](https://superuser.com/questions/161265/) first.

After solving that problem, I noticed that KDM won't let me select GNOME session. I just have KDE and xterm. I reinstalled GDM and switched to it, but I still can't start GNOME and I hate KDE4. I noticed in Synaptic that there is GNOME package available, but unfortunately, it needs both swfdec-mozilla package and extensions for epiphany browser which are on my system mutually exclusive. How to work around that? I don't use epiphany at all, so is there some other way to restore my GNOME installation?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The gnome package you're seeing is probably the meta package.  This installs everything you may possibly need for a Gnome desktop, including browsers hence the dependencies.

Is the problem that you don't want to install `swfdec-mozilla` and extensions for epiphany?  The easiest thing to do to get Gnome back is install the gnome package anyway anyway, then try removing the bits you don't need don't want.

If you can't install the gnome package through synaptic, try to [fix broken packages](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/SynapticHowto#How%20to%20fix%20broken%20packages) first.

**Edit**

Following your comment: it seems there's an [outstanding defect](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/meta-gnome2/+bug/542404), which I found from [this forum thread](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1442090).  There are a number of suggested work-arounds in the thread, maybe try installing `gnome-desktop-environment` then `gnome-extras`.

Comment: The extensions package and swfdec-mozilla  are mutually exclusive on my system. I need a way to force my system to install both. Will try with fixing broken packages.

Comment: Fixing broken packages said that everything is fine.

Comment: Somehow I missed your edit. It is the solution to problem. In light of this, I will select your answer as solution to problem.

Comment: @AndrejaKo No worries, I probably should have added a comment so you got an extra notification.  The important thing is that you did eventually solve your problem :)