# Firefox starts in off-line mode

Tags: firefox, ubuntu-10.04

I had some problems with Ubuntu previously ([This](https://superuser.com/questions/161265/after-installation-of-new-drivers-ubuntu-wont-boot-into-graphics-mode) and [this](https://superuser.com/questions/167179/ubuntu-lost-gnome-installation-cyclic-dependencies-when-reinstalling-gnome) specifically). After solving those I noticed another.

After I start computer, Firefox starts in work off-line mode. Over the time I've had similar problems with some other applications too, but only Firefox comes to mind right now. My network connection seems to be working fine however.

Even when I started Firefox in order to type this question, I was downloading updates from apt-get. When I typed http://superuser.com, Firefox told me that there I need to connect to Internet and switch to on-line mode.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check this out:
http://kb.mozillazine.org/Toolkit.networkmanager.disable
You can find this pref and change its value by typing about:config in the address bar.

Comment: That seems like the solution. During my problems, I switched away from Network Manager.